# Formula for reciprocal of a factorial

Tags: exponentiation, factorial

I was looking at some code here - https://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/6075682
when I came across this statement to calculate reciprocal of a factorial-

```
invFact(n) = fact(n)^(mod-2)
```

where mod is modulo$(10^9+7)$. The return value has to be modulo$(10^9+7)$ as well. I don't get the mathematical logic behind this formula. Can somebody guide me?
Note: invFact(n) = 1/n! here.

Comment: This function should give, for example, Invfact($120$)=$5$, right?

Comment: It's the modular inverse, $\operatorname{invFact}(n)\cdot \operatorname{fact}(n) \equiv 1 \pmod{10^9+7}$.

Comment: @ajotatxe No, it shoud be 1/120!. Its just the reciprocal.

Answer (score 1):

I found that this is the consequence of [Fermat's Little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem).

Fermat's little theorem states that if p is a prime number, then for any integer a, the number a p − a is an integer multiple of p. In the notation of modular arithmetic, this is expressed as

```
a^p = a (mod p)
```

This leads to:

```
a^(p-2) = (1/a) (mod p)
```